# With Ansible, how do I write a private key to a text file without losing the left padding?

Tags: ssh, ansible, jinja2

In other words, I want the content from an Ansible variable to be written to a particular "column" in a config file, and I don't want that content to be wrapped.

**The task:**

```yaml
- name: build cloud-init file
  local_action:
    module: ansible.builtin.template
    src: cloud_config.j2
    dest: ./cloud_config.yml
    mode: 0640
  tags: ['containers', 'containers:configuration']
```

**The variable, which lives in a vault file:**

```yaml
machineuser_key: |
    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
    b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
    ...
```

**The template:**

```yaml
write_files:
{# ssh config to allow our deployment user to fetch the Ansible repo #}
{# See https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#machine-users #}
- path: /home/{{ gcp_deploy_user }}/.ssh/{{ gcp_deploy_user}}_github_rsa
  permissions: 600
  owner: {{ gcp_deploy_user }}
  content: |
    {{ machineuser_key }}
```

**The output of that template task:**

```yaml
write_files:
- path: /home/omegasphinx/.ssh/omegasphinx_github_rsa
  permissions: 600
  owner: omegasphinx
  content: |
    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
...
```

I know that `blockinfile` is a recommended module when one wants to write a config file, and that I should use the ["Block Indication Indicator" to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41615336/785400).  But when I do these things, it still wraps the content of the ssh key.  That `blockinfile` task looks like this:

```yaml
- name: add ssh private key to cloud-init file
  local_action:
    module: ansible.builtin.blockinfile
    path: cloud_config.yml
    mode: 0440
    insertafter: "# machineuser_ssh_block"
    block: |2
      - path: /home/{{ gcp_deploy_user }}/.ssh/{{ gcp_deploy_user}}_github_rsa
        permissions: 600
        owner: {{ gcp_deploy_user }}
        content: |
          {{ machineuser_key }}
  tags: ['containers', 'containers:configuration']
```

And the `.j2` template looks like this:

```yaml
write_files:
# machineuser_ssh_block
```

The output then looks like this (exactly the same):

```yaml
write_files:
 - path: /home/omegasphinx/.ssh/omegasphinx_github_rsa
  permissions: 600
  owner: omegasphinx
  content: |
    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
...
```

**Other things I've tried:**

- I disable tabs-to-spaces in my editor and then added tabs before each line of the ssh key in the `machineuser_key` variable
- The docs say "You can manually disable the lstrip_blocks behavior by putting a plus sign (+) at the start of a block"; so I added a block and then indented the variable inside the block:

```
  {%+ if machineuser_key is defined %}
    {{ machineuser_key }} 
  {% endif %}
```

**My understanding of whitespace in Jinja2:**

To give you some context on what I'm expecting to happen.  The "[Whitespace Control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control)" section of the Jinja docs states that "a single trailing newline is stripped if present" but "other whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) is returned unchanged."  In my case, I have "other whitespace": spaces to the left of each line of the variable `machineuser_key`.  But obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your question, it's not jinja whitespace control that's jamming up your outcome, it's the fact that `machineuser_key` itself has embedded newlines; a lot of helm charts have the same problem, which allows you to take advantage of the same work-arounds:

- take advantage of the fact that YAML is a superset of JSON
- use the [`indent` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#indent) to get you and the YAML block on the same page

### JSON as YAML approach

```yaml
      - path: /home/{{ gcp_deploy_user }}/.ssh/{{ gcp_deploy_user}}_github_rsa
        permissions: 600
        owner: {{ gcp_deploy_user }}
        content: {{ machineuser_key | to_json }}
```

resulting in

```yaml
        owner: gcpawesomeuser
        content: "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\nb3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn\nETC ETC ETC\n"
```

### Using the indent filter

```yaml
      - path: /home/{{ gcp_deploy_user }}/.ssh/{{ gcp_deploy_user}}_github_rsa
        permissions: 600
        owner: {{ gcp_deploy_user }}
        content: |
          {{ machineuser_key | indent(2) }}
# with the (2) matching the number of spaces under "content" where the mustaches start
```

producing:

```yaml
        owner: gcpawesomeuser
        content: |
          -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
          b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
          ETC ETC ETC
```